# Pandas or Numpy, but I am looking to take a 500 row 1 column, I guess series, turn it in to a 100 row, 5 column. or comparable in sections

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, matrix

I am looking to take my 1 column and 500 row data, and make it either sets of 5, so 100 sets of 5. Or compare a series of 5 numbers to 5 numbers at a time ( chunks of 5 ) in the data.

I want to see how many times if any, a sequence might show up in the data, or fragments of the sequence and how often.

the numbers are from 1-69 and sets of 5. But my data is all one long column with no spaces.

I eventually want to make a list of the sets that contain 2 or more numbers with matches, but one step at a time, right.

Oh or would a 100x5 matrix work? I don't know how to do that either.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can reshape a numpy array and create a dataframe from it. Below are 100x5 adn 5x100 examples

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'data':[random.randrange(1,70) for _ in range(500)]})
pd.DataFrame(df['data'].to_numpy().reshape((100, 5)))
pd.DataFrame(df['data'].to_numpy().reshape((5, 100)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It was so easy. I put in a '.' and not a ',' the first few times .